# How to set variable check to a whole index.php document + includes?

Tags: php, variables

I want to check if variable is defined or not. The code below works fine within the PHP tags, but it does not work past the PHP tag.

```
<?php
if(empty($var))
{
echo 'Not found!';
}
echo "$test";
?>
```

For example: In case I have a short PHP code inside my usual HTML code.

```
<div class="card-header">
<font class="card-headline"><?php echo "$weeks"; ?></font>
</div>
```

If var $weeks is not set I would like it to echo 'Not found!' but it only works within mentioned tags.

**Is it possible to extend it somehow that I only have to add the if(empty) condition into a header file and it checks the variables from header.php to footer.php since they both are included within the index.php.**

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Where are you setting $weeks at?

Comment: PHP is unaffected by tags - its own, or of HTML elemnts, or any other. It's all about the scope of your variable. A global variable can be interrogated anywhere after it's set. So in your output, you could do `<?= !empty($weeks) ? $weeks : 'Not found!' ?>`

Comment: Yes - Put in the header something like `if(empty($var)) { $var = ""; }` and then you can output an empty string (Or set any other default value). If that is what you mean

Comment: [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) **does not** check if a variable is set, [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) does. And it works everywhere.

Comment: @axiac You are wrong. "A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE." Read more in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: @Daerik maybe my previous comment is misleading. Its meaning is: *"`empty()` is not the correct function to check if a variable is set"*. It returns `TRUE` for both unset and set variables (`0`, `''`, `array()` etc).

Comment: I have a list of php documents with over 500 variables already defined. And then I have an another php document (for example: action.php) that uses that data. My problem is that when I add a new variable to my action.php but somehow forget to define that same variable in my variables php document, then I would like to get a grip of that. At the moment I get empty space - sometimes just a missing word etc. I would like to see it visually if I forgot to define something.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following in order to set a variable within the script, assuming you've set `$weeks` somewhere above:

```
<?php

$test = 'Example test set';

if(empty($weeks)) {
    $weeks = 'Not found!';
} else {
    $weeks = $test;
}
?>
```

And then in your HTML, you could simply echo the variable `$weeks`, based on if it's set or not.

```
<div class="card-header">
<font class="card-headline"><?php echo $weeks; ?></font>
</div>
```

Comment: Can this be done universally? If I have like 50 variables that I want to check and I don't want to type all those in manually? For example: I am pulling content from multiple databases and sometimes a completely new variable comes up (is created) that needs a definition. I hope that my explanation was clear enough :)

Comment: Maybe you should consider engineering things in a different way? Maybe shove all of your variables into an array and then assign them to a unique key? This way, you still have to do some typing, but it'll be easier to manage going forward. Maybe someone has a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading up on [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) when mixing `PHP` with `HTML`. In your specific case, I would suggest using a [ternary conditional operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php).

Here is an example:

```
<div class="card-header">
  <font class="card-headline"><?php echo !empty($weeks) ? $weeks : 'Not found!'; ?></font>
</div>
```

Or with shorthand:

```
<div class="card-header">
  <font class="card-headline"><?php echo @$weeks ?: 'Not found!'; ?></font>
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to upset a lot of people with that suppression operator! :P

Comment: Haha! I know. It's just the only way to get around an unset variable without throwing a warning in this particular syntax.